# Animate centerViewTo(xIndex , yVal, AxisDependency in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using `centerViewTo` method in MPandroid chart in which the chart centers itself to a bar on which the user clicks.
But the centering happens very fast . I want to slow down this process by using some kind of animation or some duration. So the transition becomes smooth.

How to do that?

Comment: Did not understand what you are saying. Need some more details.

Comment: @activesince93 Say I have crated a BarChart. Now when the user clicks on any Bar that bar comes in the center and gets highlighted. I have succesfully brought that bar to center using `onChartValueSelectedListener`  but that centering is happening very quickly and you can not see that transition. I want to slow down that process so that user can see the bars moving and the one which he clicked on coming to center slowly.

Comment: Can you give me the link to `centerViewTo` method? I wanna take look at it.

Comment: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/db1fc396efa47a1b33739c087274d8a03cb4be7a/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/BarLineChartBase.java

This the link for the file in which `centerViewTo` method is there.